# Returning a value from Javascript to HTML button and passing it on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, return-value

A lot of web technology is over my head so I'm wondering if someone could help me. I have a button on a webpage that when clicked calls off to a `jQuery.ajax` post request javascript function. This function uses the success to slightly manipulate the data returned.

I need to return the data sent back to the html side for use later in other javascript function. The confusion lies in the fact that it is an html button that calls this function. I need this information, so that when another button is clicked, I can send this data along with another post call.

Could someone point me out in the direction to get this started? All the functionality is already in place except for actually passing the information along (in other words buttons, and ajax calls). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but I believe the style of your question (and the lack of any code, i.e. proof you're trying stuff yourself) is not a good fit for SO. Please read [the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I apologize, I am relatively new to using SO, so I'm getting used to some of the basics of how it is moderated. I will certainly keep this in mind and read over the FAQ's more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to store your value in a global variable.

Or store it in a hidden input element.

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools, which is widely disliked across StackOverflow (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve. (If you use Google Search, and you have a Google account, you can [easily block results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) from w3schools)

Comment: well i have nothing against the site as i can filter the information i need from it. i removed the links if it can mislead someone.

Comment: Thanks! This was actually enough of a suggestion for me to look up some information to get where I needed to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global var/object in the page, and update this object with whatever data your post is returning.

So:

```
var dataStore = {};  (Could any type: array, {}, string, etc..)
```

In your success callback:

```
dataStore.happyValue = data.happyData;
```

The data in this case would be completely hidden from the user and you could more or less use it whenever you like.

You could also take the value returned form the success callback and assign it to an element in the page.  This could be a hidden input, div, whatever.

In this example I'm storing the data using the data attr:

```
<div data-store="" id="some-div">.....</div>
```

In your success callback:

```
$('#some-div').data('store',data.happyData);
```

You can then access your data later on with the following:

```
$('#some-div').data('store');
```

The approach you end up using and sticking with is really dependent on both what it is you're trying to accomplish and how extensible you'd like your code to be.